# Puppeteer attach to running chrome that launched by selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, puppeteer

Is it possible for puppeteer attach to a running Chrome that launched by selenium webdriver?

My automated tests are based on protractor/selenium/typescript, one of the test is going to download file in headless chrome, but download is not working due to an known bug(https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481). I found a solution for headless download is that - using puppeteer send 'Page.setDownloadBehavior' command, then the file can be downloaded in headless.

For example, I have 10 tests, test1 ~ test9 are running on Chrome that launched by selenium webdriver, test 10 is download file test, I use puppeteer to download file in headless, but puppeteer launched another chrome instance. So is it possible for puppeteer attach to a running Chrome that launched by selenium webdriver?